# Using C#, is there a method to restore a database from a multi-file backup detecting which files are full vs diff?

Tags: sql-server, c#

I know there is functionality to restore databases in C#, however if I am given 2 or more files in a directory containing a full and differential backup files I would like to:

1) Determine which file is the full and which is the differential

2) Restore them in the correct order

Is there a straight-forward way to do this in C# .NET i.e. a function which accepts a list of files, automatically determines the order to restore them and does so?

Or do I have to create such functionality myself by reading the backup headers to determine the full vs diff and restore them that way.

I have seen articles like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254269/using-smo-restore-class-when-there-are-multiple-backup-points-in-bak-file

And I can tell there should be a way to detect what kind of file the backup is:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backupsettype

But I just can't piece it all together.

Any ideas appreciated.
m